# Extract hour from timestamp in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to extract hour and see if this value is within specific range. And I am getting the error saying: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`. Column type is datetime64.

Here's how my data looks like: (dataframe stores exactly same data)

```
captureTime     id      occupancy   power   temperature
6/26/2017 0:25  1345    0           1.2     72.96
```

Time column looks like this : 6/26/17 0:04

My code is below:

```
if ( (df_mean['date'].dt.hour >= 6) & (df_mean['date'].dt.hour < 20) ):
```

I've tried this one as well:

```
if ( (df_mean['captureTime'].dt.hour >= 6) and (df_mean['captureTime'].dt.hour < 20) ):
```

Any advice?

Comment: What is `df_mean` in your code?

Comment: @spuente it is a dataframe storing several columns.

Comment: Could you provide a basic sample of your dataframe? (with column names)

Comment: @spuente I just updated with dataset.

Comment: The condition in the `if` statement has a different true or false value for each row in the data frame. When exactly you want to enter into the if block? If all are true? If any is true? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
if ( (df_mean['date'].dt.hour >= 6) & (df_mean['date'].dt.hour < 20) ):
```

You are treating an array of booleans as if it were a boolean.  It is not, it is an array.  Take it one step at a time:

```
match = df_mean['date'].dt.hour.between(6, 19)
```

Then you can do things like:

```
if match.any():

if match.all():

if match.sum() > len(df) / 2:
```

Or you can subset your original data:

```
good_data = df_mean[match]
bad_data = df_mean[~match]
```

And so on.

Comment: Thanks! I've filtered dataframe and it works. Here's my final code `df_mean = df_mean[ ...& df_mean['date'].dt.hour.between(6,19)]`